# Support for distributing benefits in Turkish

Tags: households

Can CiviCRM be quickly setup in a cloud so that it's primary function is to distribute benefits (cash, food, etc) with user interface in Turkish?

Answer (score 1):

you would have to check how complete the turkish translation is. It seems we have achieved 100% translated, but can't judge of the quality of the translation.

https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/

They are various hosting providers that can offer you to host. We do host on our own servers, so don't have a first hand experience on what they offer and it is not a question that fits the SE format, but I can mention that a nice community member is fast at replying and has a lot of experience with civi: hershel, you can find more on civihosting

and this page lists other providers, that are all active in the community:
https://civicrm.org/hosting-providers